# Real Analysis, Folland Proposition 2.16 and Corollary 2.17 Integration of Nonnegative functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

**Background Information:**

> Proposition 2.16 - If $f\in L^+$, then $\int f = 0$ iff $f = 0$ a.e.

Proof - Suppose $f = \sum_{j}a_j\chi_{E_j}$, then $\int f = 0$ iff $a_j = 0$ or $\mu(E_j) = 0$. In general, if $f = 0$ a.e., and $\phi$ is a simple function with $0\leq\phi\leq f$ then $\phi = 0$ a.e. and we have $$\int f = \sup_{\phi\leq f}\int \phi = 0$$ Conversely, suppose $E_n = \{f\geq \frac{1}{n}\}$, then $$\int f \geq \int \frac{1}{n}\chi_{E_n} = \frac{1}{n}\mu(E_n)$$ So, $$\mu(E_n)\leq n\int f = 0$$ then $$\mu(\{f\geq 0\}) = \mu\left(\bigcup_{n}E_n\right) = 0$$

I am pretty sure this proof is correct. My question now pertains to the Corollary of this proposition:

**Question:**

> Corollary 2.17 - If $\{f_n\}\subset L^+$, and $f_n(x)$ increases to $f(x)$ for a.e. $x$, then $\int f = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int f_n$.

My idea: Let $f = \sum_{1}^{n}a_j\chi_{E_j}$ then $\{E_j\}_{j}$ is a finite disjoint family of measurable functions such that $X = \bigcup_{j}E_j$. We have that $f_n(x)$ increases to $f(x)$ for a.e. $x$ this means that there is a measurable set $F$ such that $x\in F$ with $\mu(F) = 0$. Then $f_n$ increases to $f$ on $X\setminus E$ and then applying the Monotone Convergence theorem $$\int \chi_{X\setminus E}f_n\rightarrow \int \chi_{X\setminus E} f = \int f$$

My apologies if this is a bit messy. Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume the notation $L^+$ refers to the set of measurable functions from $X$ to $[0,\infty]$ (or maybe $[0,\infty)$), where $X$ is some measure space. Is this correct? If so, then why are you assuming that $f$ can be written in the form $\sum_{1}^{n}a_j \chi_{E_j}$? In other words, you seem to be assuming that $f$ is a simple function.

Comment: Yes $L^+$ is the set of measurable functions from $X$ to $[0,\infty]$. I am letting $f$ be a simple function, I don't think there is anything wrong with that. But I could be wrong

Comment: But a sequence $(f_n)$ of arbitrary elements of $L^+$ will not generally converge to a simple function, not even if all of the $f_n$'s are simple functions.

Comment: P.S. you are citing the monotone convergence theorem in your proof, but isn't that exactly what corollary 2.17 is?

Comment: I see your point, Folland has MCT as Theorem 14, I made a post on that earlier.

Comment: OK, I checked my copy of Folland.  The only difference between what he calls the monotone convergence theorem (2.14) and corollary 2.17 is that 2.14 assumes convergence everywhere, whereas 2.17 relaxes the assumption to convergence almost everywhere. But then 2.17 is a very easy consequence of 2.14. Did you read/understand his proof? It's only one sentence long :-)

Comment: He usually doesn't provide detailed proofs. But no I did not fully understand his proof.

Comment: I'll post an answer which provides more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: your proof of 2.17 is incorrect, because you assume that an arbitrary element $f \in L^+$ can be written as $f = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}a_j \chi_{E_j}$, but in fact this is only true of simple functions. Note that nonnegative simple functions are elements of $L^+$, but a general element of $L^+$ is any measurable function from $X$ to $[0,\infty]$.

We wish to prove Corollary 2.17, which is as follows.

> **Corollary 2.17:** If $f_n$ is a sequence of functions in $L^+$, and $f \in L^+$, and $f_n(x)$ increases to $f(x)$ for almost every $x$, then $\int f = \lim \int f_n$.

This is very similar to Theorem 2.14, the Monotone Convergence Theorem, which states:

> **Theorem 2.14:** If $f_n$ is a sequence of functions in $L^+$, and $f_j \leq f_{j+1}$ for all $j$, and $f = \lim f_n (= \sup f_n)$, then $\int f = \lim \int f_n$.

The only difference is that 2.14 assumes convergence everywhere, whereas 2.17 relaxes this to convergence almost everywhere. Let's see how to use Theorem 2.17 to prove Corollary 2.17.

We will also use Proposition 2.16, which states:

> **Proposition 2.16:** If $f \in L^+$, then $\int f = 0$ iff $f = 0$ almost everywhere.

**Proof of Corollary 2.17**

We are given that $f_n \in L^+$ and $f \in L^+$, and $f_n(x)$ increases to $f(x)$ for almost every $x$. So, let $E$ denote the set of those $x$ for which $f_n(x)$ does **not** increase to $f(x)$. Then $E$ has measure zero (by definition of "almost everywhere"), and $f_n(x)$ increases to $f(x)$ for **every** element of $X \setminus E$. Therefore,
$$\int_{X \setminus E}f = \int_X f \chi_{X \setminus E} = \lim \int_X f_n \chi_{X \setminus E} = \lim \int_{X \setminus E}f_n\quad\quad(*)$$
where the middle equality holds by the Monotone Convergence Theorem (2.14) since $f_n \chi_{X \setminus E}(x)$ increases to $f \chi_{X \setminus E}(x)$ for every $x \in X$.

Now, note that $\int_E f = \int_X f \chi_E = 0$ by Proposition 2.16 (since $f \chi_E = 0$ almost everywhere). Similarly, $\int_E f_n = 0$. Equation $(*)$ remains true if we add zero to both sides, so:
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_X f &=
\underbrace{\int_{E} f}_{=0} + \int_{X \setminus E}f \\
&= \lim\underbrace{\int_{E}f_n}_{=0} + \lim\int_{X \setminus E}f_n \\
&= \lim\left(\int_{E}f_n + \int_{X \setminus E}f_n \right) \\
&= \lim \int_X f_n \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Actually, Folland takes the same approach in making $f$ simple. He could of made a mistake though...

Comment: @Wolfy In which proof? I don't see him making that assumption in the proof of 2.17.

Comment: If you look at proposition 2.16, he has $f$ being a simple function

Comment: @Wolfy: Right, in the first sentence he shows that it is true if $f$ is simple. But starting with the second sentence he assumes $f$ is a general element of $L^+$ and uses the fact that the integral of $f$ is defined as the supremum of the integrals of simple functions $\phi$ such that $\phi \leq f$. (Now that I read your proof of 2.16 more carefully, I see that you are doing the same thing.)

Comment: Correct, and I did pretty much the same general case so I am not sure why my proposition 2.16

Comment: @Wolfy Yes, I think your 2.16 is OK. Only 2.17 is problematic because you assume $f$ is simple and don't extend this to the general case. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok, thank you just wanted to make sure. I have skimmed your proof it looks really good, I will look at it more, proving proposition 2.20 now

Comment: @Wolfy: Note that we don't have to approach 2.17 by starting with simple functions and generalizing, because Folland already did this for us in 2.14. So, 2.14 applies to general functions in $L^+$, and we just need to extend to the case where convergence is almost everywhere instead of everywhere.

Comment: Quick question why did you write $$\int_E f = \int_X \chi_E$$ Couldn't we just say $$\int_E f = \int f\chi_E$$ I can see how both are going to be zero since $\mu(E) = 0$ but I am not sure why you put the subscript $X$ there

Comment: @Wolfy Sure, I was just emphasizing that the integral on the right hand side is taken over the entire space $X$.

Comment: Ok, that is what I thought just wanted to clarify thanks.